# Poor NVME SSD Performance (only on Linux)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hard-drive, ssd, nvme

I'm using the dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu operating systems. I've Adata s40g NVME SSD 3500/1200 NVME m2 SSD. The SSD performing 2200/1200 on my Windows operating system and 1000/400 on my Linux operating system. **I tried recommended SSD optimizations from wiki.debian.org.**

**The results are awesome in my test with the fio tool. But test results are very bad in my test with the Gnome Disks and hdparm tools. When opening software like phpStorm, I don't feel the speed I tested with fio.**

**What should I do? What are the optimizations I need to do?**

uname -a

```
Linux empat 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

hdparm -tT --direct /dev/nvme0n1

```
/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing O_DIRECT cached reads:   830 MB in  2.00 seconds = 414.69 MB/sec
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 2940 MB in  3.00 seconds = 979.84 MB/sec
```

cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler

```
[none] mq-deadline
```

hdparm -v /dev/nvme0n1

```
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 244198/64/32, sectors = 500118192, start = 0
```

fstab

```
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=148d65bf-3ce9-4e33-a482-e5c9759069b0 /               ext4   discard,noatime,commit=600,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=8CCF-2BC6  /boot/efi       vfat    discard,noatime,commit=600,umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=fcda5d21-154a-4fae-84af-8e4843e757ab none            swap    sw,discard              0       0
```

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 54084620-4425-1420-1048-06C60C5CEFDE

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048 150390783 150388736  71,7G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 218634240 226635775   8001536   3,8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 226635776 227719167   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 227719168 227923967    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6 227923968 227956735     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p7 227956736 500117503 272160768 129,8G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 874FF78E-6655-4F9E-B903-C40B95318A77

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 1953523711 1953259520 931,4G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

inxi -d

```
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1256.3GB (14.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: XPG_SPECTRIX_S40G size: 256.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10EZEX size: 1000.2GB
           Optical-1: /dev/sr0 model: N/A dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 48x multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5762 (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d5 (rev 01)
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
03:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] (rev ef)
0a:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
0b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
0b:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
0b:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB 3.0 Host controller
0c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
0c:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
0c:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=write --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=1024k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=10000 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting

```
TEST: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-3.1
Starting 1 process
TEST: Laying out IO file (1 file / 500MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)][63.6%][r=0KiB/s,w=1196MiB/s][r=0,w=1196 IOPS][eta 00m:04s]
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)][100.0%][r=0KiB/s,w=1170MiB/s][r=0,w=1170 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
TEST: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3364: Sat Dec 21 02:57:52 2019
  write: IOPS=984, BW=984MiB/s (1032MB/s)(10.0GiB/10406msec)
    slat (usec): min=42, max=26125, avg=119.63, stdev=564.49
    clat (msec): min=3, max=307, avg=32.21, stdev=23.62
     lat (msec): min=3, max=307, avg=32.33, stdev=23.62
    clat percentiles (msec):
     |  1.00th=[    4],  5.00th=[   17], 10.00th=[   26], 20.00th=[   27],
     | 30.00th=[   27], 40.00th=[   27], 50.00th=[   27], 60.00th=[   27],
     | 70.00th=[   28], 80.00th=[   32], 90.00th=[   41], 95.00th=[   82],
     | 99.00th=[  121], 99.50th=[  186], 99.90th=[  284], 99.95th=[  292],
     | 99.99th=[  300]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=208896, max=1222656, per=99.40%, avg=1001574.40, stdev=323115.31, samples=20
   iops        : min=  204, max= 1194, avg=978.10, stdev=315.54, samples=20
  lat (msec)   : 4=1.02%, 10=2.00%, 20=3.05%, 50=86.82%, 100=5.16%
  lat (msec)   : 250=1.68%, 500=0.28%
  cpu          : usr=4.05%, sys=7.54%, ctx=10038, majf=0, minf=12
  IO depths    : 1=0.2%, 2=0.4%, 4=0.8%, 8=1.6%, 16=3.3%, 32=93.6%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=99.8%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.2%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwt: total=0,10240,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=984MiB/s (1032MB/s), 984MiB/s-984MiB/s (1032MB/s-1032MB/s), io=10.0GiB (10.7GB), run=10406-10406msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=0/41134, merge=0/97, ticks=0/1274531, in_queue=1186048, util=97.23%
```

fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=read --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=1024k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=10000 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting

```
 fio-3.1
    Starting 1 process
    Jobs: 1 (f=1): [R(1)][100.0%][r=3087MiB/s,w=0KiB/s][r=3087,w=0 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
    TEST: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3461: Sat Dec 21 02:59:05 2019
       read: IOPS=3077, BW=3078MiB/s (3227MB/s)(10.0GiB/3327msec)
        slat (usec): min=29, max=459, avg=71.77, stdev=26.48
        clat (usec): min=2423, max=27253, avg=10198.97, stdev=2090.10
         lat (usec): min=2501, max=27330, avg=10271.30, stdev=2087.83
        clat percentiles (usec):
         |  1.00th=[ 2573],  5.00th=[ 6652], 10.00th=[10159], 20.00th=[10159],
         | 30.00th=[10159], 40.00th=[10290], 50.00th=[10290], 60.00th=[10290],
         | 70.00th=[10290], 80.00th=[10290], 90.00th=[10421], 95.00th=[12125],
         | 99.00th=[18482], 99.50th=[19268], 99.90th=[23987], 99.95th=[25560],
         | 99.99th=[26870]
       bw (  MiB/s): min= 3044, max= 3088, per=99.98%, avg=3077.33, stdev=16.72, samples=6
       iops        : min= 3044, max= 3088, avg=3077.33, stdev=16.72, samples=6
      lat (msec)   : 4=2.64%, 10=5.57%, 20=91.67%, 50=0.13%
      cpu          : usr=0.96%, sys=23.60%, ctx=10096, majf=0, minf=8204
      IO depths    : 1=0.2%, 2=0.4%, 4=0.8%, 8=1.6%, 16=3.3%, 32=93.6%, >=64=0.0%
         submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
         complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=99.8%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.2%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
         issued rwt: total=10240,0,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
         latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

    Run status group 0 (all jobs):
       READ: bw=3078MiB/s (3227MB/s), 3078MiB/s-3078MiB/s (3227MB/s-3227MB/s), io=10.0GiB (10.7GB), run=3327-3327msec
```

Comment: Presuming your SSD firmware is up-to-date, there are lots of questions on this site about slow copies,... Some people are helped by changing swappiness, or turning swap off entirely.  What have you tried?  The sda alignment (34 start)  may also affect that device's read/write rates.

Comment: Your benchmark block size is huge (1 MByte), you are running your benchmark for a tiny amount of time (60 seconds), you can likely use a higher iodepth and doesn't 3078MiB/s sound a bit /too/ high for your read speeds? As you elided the disk output from that run we can't easily see if it just all came from cache... Opening software is likely limited by reads and those reads may not be big, chunky sequential ones (and may involve metadata operations)...

Comment: What should I do as a result?

Comment: @Empat For fio you can try to increase the time you run I/O for, use a smaller block size, set `rw` to randread/randwrite, if you can stand IRRECOVERABLY DESTROYING the data already on your disk do I/O directly against the block device and see if the fio speed drops to match your other tools.